# Merge Datarows using sql

Tags: sql, vb.net

i have a table like this:
[Datatable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BdVEz.jpg)

and i need to modify it like this:-
[Required Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1OlXK.jpg)

i have to merge operation name which have same operation type, machine and attachment and then sum up the [sam] of merged operations.

i tried this but getting errors

```
SELECT [operation_type],
       [operation_name],
       [machine_type],
       [attachment],
       Stuff((SELECT '+' + t2.operation_name 
          FROM   ob 
          WHERE  [operation_type] = t2.[operation_type] 
                 AND [machine_type] = t2.[machine_type] 
                 AND [attachment] = t2.[attachment] 
          FOR xml path ('')), 1, 1, '') AS NAME 
FROM   ob AS t2 
GROUP  BY operation_type
```

Comment: MySql <> Sql what one is it... My best guess is SQL as the syntax is SQL. Please update tags...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
    operation_type,
    STUFF((SELECT '+' + ob.operation_name 
           FROM ob
           WHERE  
               operation_type = t2.operation_type
               AND machine_type = t2.machine_type 
               AND attachment = t2.attachment 
           FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') AS 'Operation_Name' ,
    machine_type,
    attachment,
    SUM(SAM) AS 'SAM'
FROM   
    ob AS t2 
GROUP BY 
    t2.operation_type, t2.machine_type, t2.attachment
```

Thank you!

Comment: Overflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: Thanks heybro but it is giving error as follows   (Syntax error in query expression 'Stuff((SELECT '+' + ob.operation_name FROM ob WHERE operation_type = t2.operation_type AND machine_type = t2.machine_type AND attachment = t2.attachment FOR xml path ('')), 1, 1, '')'.)